# create .ipa for jailbroken devices?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I just finished my first iphone application and after i build i got .app file in build folder
How can I create an IPA file ,that jailbroken devices can install it easy?

i Create a folder named Payload then i Copy Myapp.app into the Payload directory...Compress the Payload directory and rename the zip file to Myapp.ipa but when i want to run it in my device this error "the application "Myapp" cannot be opened" occurred.

Answer (score 3):

this site was helpful for me.

http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398#more-398