# Building An IPA Using Apple's Tools & Certificate For Jailbroken Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, xcodebuild, ipa

How do I crack my own IPA file for jailbroken distribution?
Or alternatively how do I build an IPA that will work on a jailbroken phone?

I purchased an apple certificate and am able to build an Xcode 4 ipa file that works on my device as well as devices of official beta testers. However, I would like to have an "open beta" for everyone since the application is essentially free.

So I would like to build a version of the IPA that works on jailbroken devices, essentially crack my own application... I found [this](http://my.opera.com/iphonedev/blog/2008/08/11/how-to-crack-apple-apps) which seems ridiculously hard and there is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509793/create-ipa-for-jailbroken-devices) which answers a slightly different question. I want this process to be automated by my build server so I hope its relatively reasonable.

I've tried manually building zips, building for the app store etc. and it all failed on the jailbroken device that I have. It might be a fluke with this particular device but I find it hard to find information for this particular use case, so maybe one of the things I did is "the right thing" and its just by bad lack that it didn't work (hopefully someone can confirm what "needs doing").

Comment: if you wanna distribute for the cydia then you only need to sign with the ldid. other signing is not required (you don't need to use your apple certificate). You can bind the ldid from the mac to the Xcode compile procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I considered cydia packaging but then the packaging process would be different and just going into that seems like a pain. I don't want to start hosting a repository since beta apps aren't really something that needs that. Just a simple link in the website people can click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install a build of the application using debug credentials on the jailbroken device. I'm guessing the beta tester who used the device just did something wrong with a previous install attempt.

Comment: You could also look into something called `iReSign`.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that option but it wasn't really relevant for me since it requires a Mac (which beta testers might not have) and a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this would break Apple's EULA.

The point of the IPA is to ensure that it will only run on selected devices, i would recommend against this, and stick with closed beta until release time.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in any way and isn't helpful. We do have lawyers so I will take their advice when the time comes. Since jailbreaking falls under fair use I'm pretty sure this does too.